# Rails 5.2 Association callbacks not firing on before_add or before_remove

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, associations

I have an Activity model with HABTM:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :contacts,
                        -> { distinct },
                        before_add: :contact_calculate_score,
                        before_remove: :contact_calculate_score


def contact_calculate_score(contact)
  binding.pry
  contact.calculate_score
end
```

There are quite a few questions on this, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513529/rails-after-add-association-callback-not-triggering).

I have tried using '<<' to insert activities into contacts, but still the callback does not fire. Why is it not being called?

As far as I can see, it is not the issue described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40665060/rails-habtm-after-add-callback-fires-before-saving-primary-object) either.

Comment: Where is the `calculate_score` method being defined?

Comment: @Jake It is in a concern on the Contact model - but notice the 'binding.pry' -> does not hit that, so contact_score is not even being called yet, because the callback code itself is not entered.

Comment: Ok so this is partly related to the '<<' issue in the first question I linked to -> it is about which side of the HABTM you insert the records from. Will add an answer shortly after I test that theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the code is correct, the issue was my expectation did not match what I was doing in the console, which was this:

```
"a contact_instance".activities << "an activity instance"
```

eg:

```
   Contact.first.activities << Activity.create(...)
```

I would have to define the callbacks in the `Contact` model for that to work.

Alternatively, to get my callbacks to fire, I have to push a `Contact` instance into the contacts for an `Activity`:

```
"an activity instance".contacts << "a contact_instance"
```

eg:

```
Activity.first.contacts << Contact.create(...) or Contact.find(...) etc
```